# Closing idle consumer which handles long running task in rabbitmq pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, pika

I have a specific case where I need to close a consumer if it does not receive any new messages for 5 minutes. The work that a consumer does when it receives a message is long-running (say 15-30 mins). I am able to handle long-running tasks by following the example mentioned in pika's [github repo](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/main/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py). However in this case, I couldn't figure out how I would close the consumer if it remains idle for 5 minutes. Other than this, I also checked out BlockingConnections' consume generator where I can set an inactivity_timeout 5 minutes which will close the consumer after 5 idle minutes. However, I don't know how I could integrate this with a multi-threaded consumer so that I can handle long-running tasks as well in this case. Otherwise, I keep running into connection-closed errors after a particular message is consumed. How do I resolve this? Some inputs would be helpful. Thanks.

A snippet of what my consumer looks like. It's not working as I expect it to at the moment:

```py
import time
import pika
import threading
import functools
from typing import Callable

class RabbitMQClient:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int, user: str, password: str, heartbeat: int = 60, **kwargs):
        self.__credentials = {"host": host, "port": port, "user": user, "password": password}
        self.heartbeat = heartbeat
        self.__consumer_handler = None
        self.connection = self.__create_connection(**self.__credentials, heartbeat=self.heartbeat)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.connection.close()
        except:
            pass

    # Create new connection
    @staticmethod
    def __create_connection(**kwargs):
        param = pika.ConnectionParameters(kwargs.get("host"), kwargs.get("port"), '/',
                                          pika.PlainCredentials(kwargs.get("user"), kwargs.get("password")),
                                          heartbeat=kwargs.get("heartbeat"))
        return pika.BlockingConnection(param)


     @staticmethod
    def __ack_message(channel, delivery_tag, ack):
        """Note that `channel` must be the same pika channel instance via which
        the message being ACKed was retrieved (AMQP protocol constraint).
        """
        if channel.is_open:
            if ack:
                channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)
            else:
                channel.basic_nack(delivery_tag, requeue=False)
        else:
            pass

    def __on_message(self, channel, method_frame, properties, body, args):
        def do_work():
            delivery_tag, binding_key = method_frame.delivery_tag, method_frame.routing_key
            # Simulating a long running task here
            time.sleep(1800)
            cb = functools.partial(self.__ack_message, channel, delivery_tag, ack=True)
            connection.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)

        (connection, threads) = args
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_work)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)  

    def consume_data(self, queue: str, exchange: str):
            channel = self.channel
            channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange, exchange_type='direct')

            threads = []
            for method, properties, body in channel.consume(queue, auto_ack=False, inactivity_timeout=900):
                if body:
                    on_message_callback = functools.partial(self.__on_message, args=(self.connection, threads))
                    on_message_callback(channel, method, properties, body)
                else:
                    print('breaking')
                    break

            # Wait for all to complete
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()

            channel.cancel()
```

Comment: Hello, I'm the primary maintainer for Pika. The easiest way for me to review your code is for you to share a COMPLETE, running example via a GitHub repository. I can then "comment" via pull requests that will hopefully improve your code. Giving feedback via StackOverflow is too cumbersome for me to bother.

Comment: Hi @LukeBakken, thanks for reaching out. I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/AdirthaBorgohain/rabbitmq-examples) for a small running example.  My final goal here is to make the consumer such that it exits if it remains idle without recieving any new message for some specific amount of time (say for example 2 minutes) Thanks. Maybe we need to use consumer generator somehow. Just not sure how.

Comment: Also, since the tasks will be long running (15-20 mins), I need to make sure there's no connection closed issue due to missing heartbeats or other reasons. Hence, we probably need to use consumer generator somehow with threads?

Comment: Perfect,thank you. I am on PTO the next week but I will return to this.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot. Looking forward to your inputs.

Comment: @LukeBakken Reminder bump.

Comment: Please be patient.

Comment: https://github.com/AdirthaBorgohain/rabbitmq-examples/issues/1#issuecomment-1184924944

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar issue wherein my long-running task terminates the program at the end of its execution. I have a job queue defined with a maxsize of 1 and am triggering the long-running task after consuming from the rabbitmq queue one at a time. I have posted a question for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904381/pyhtonrabbitmqpikachannel-is-closed-error-while-executing-long-running-tas). Possible for anyone to look at the question and help answer the query.

Comment: @Viktor1903, after your long-running task completes do you see the "required argument is not an integer" error? I am getting the same error when the ack callback is being called. The error occurs when encode function is called. It throws an error when it appends '>Q' string with the delivery_tag. Not sure what this string is though. Let me know if you are running into the same issue. The following is the piece of code where it fails:<br/>
        `def encode(self):<br/>
             pieces = list()<br/>
             pieces.append(struct.pack('>Q', self.delivery_tag))`<br/>

Comment: Nope. I am sorry. I have no issues with the acks. I usually use the `add_callback_threadsafe()` method to perform acks.