# Channel is closed error while executing long running task from job_queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, pika

I have a job_queue implemented in python which is subscribed on to rabbitmq queue. The rabbitmq queue is updated from a server periodically. No fixed timelines as to when the rabbitmq would be populated. When this happens, the business logic is to run a long-running task where these tasks could be anywhere between 5 minutes, up to 5 hours.

In my job_queue implementation, I have set the max size to be 1 and the prefetch count for the connection to be 1. This is to allow only one event from the rabbitmq to be picked up at a time. The intention is to pick up one event, execute it and then proceed to another. I have also set the heartbeat setting of the connection as 0, which I believe implies don't timeout. Yet I notice that I get a **Channel is closed.** error when there is more than 1 event in the rabbitmq and it terminates my code block. Would appreciate pointers as to how best to run my long-running task without the rabbitmq timeouts or connection timeout failures.

A small excerpt from my code-block representing the job queue and the callbacks is as follows:

class slave:
def **init**(self):
self.job_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
self.job_item = ""

```
def push_to_job_queue(self, obj):
    print("Inside push_to_job_queue")
    try:
        self.job_item = obj
        self.job_queue.put(self.job_item)
        threading.Thread(target=self.get_from_job_queue, daemon=True).start()
        print("JobQueue being joined")
        self.job_queue.join()
    except Exception as e:
        self.job_queue.join()
        print("Failure in slaveConsumer.py report: {}".format(e), "error")

def get_from_job_queue(self):
    # def _worker():
    print("Inside get_from_job_queue")
    if self.job_queue.empty() and self.job_queue.qsize() == 0:
        print("Queue is Empty do nothing")
    else:
        json_body = self.job_queue.get()
        # This is a long running task
        self._parse_object_from_queue(json_body)
        self.job_queue.task_done()
```

Comment: On further analysis of the problem, I was able to resolve the channel error. I did this by following the example listed on the [official pika website](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/6dd6f7b100425e835ad363ef1b96786d0ff8389e/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py#L40). I am now running into the issue where once the long-running task is done the acknowledgment is failing. It fails when creating a struct.pack. Would anyone have ideas about how to go about fixing this:

`def encode(self):
             pieces = list()
             pieces.append(struct.pack('>Q', self.delivery_tag))`

Comment: Hello, I maintain the Pika library. If you provide complete, runnable code that I can use to reproduce the issue I'm sure I can figure it out quickly. Open an issue here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues